# ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error on flink RUN command through ENTRYPOINT

Tags: dockerfile, apache-flink

I have set up Apache Flink on an EKS Kubernetes cluster with one Job Manager and two Task Managers.
While running command getting below error:

```
flink run -c myClass /opt/flink/lib/myflink.jar
```

Error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '17…’ at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '31….’ at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '6c478…’ at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '249….’ at 'null' in 'null'
08:49:12.383 [main] ERROR org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend - Error while running the command.
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute sql
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[myflink.jar:?]
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:240) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) [myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165) [myflink.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:867) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:827) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:918) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:730) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at myClass.main(myclass.java:157) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'insert-into_default_catalog.default_database.Correlation'.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2203) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:206) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutor.executeAsync(DefaultExecutor.java:95) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:850) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:827) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:918) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:730) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at myClass.main(myClass.java:157) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$11(RestClusterClient.java:448) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:271) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$12(FutureUtils.java:489) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843) ~[myflink.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125) ~[myflink.jar:?]
```

Above flink run command works fine when I login to pod and submit manually. Facing issue only when submiting through ENTRYPOING in dockerfile:

```
# Use the flink:1.16 base image
FROM flink:1.16.1 AS base

# Make directories for the plugins and copy the required JAR files
RUN mkdir -p /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop \
    && cp /opt/flink/opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.1.jar /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/ \
    && mkdir -p /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-presto \
    && cp /opt/flink/opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-1.16.1.jar /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-presto/

COPY .jar /opt/flink/lib/ myflink.jar

RUN chown flink:flink /opt/flink/lib/myflink.jar

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chown flink:flink docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 6123
EXPOSE 6122
EXPOSE 6124
EXPOSE 6125
EXPOSE 6126

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Run the Flink job in the foreground and suppress exit code
flink run -c myClass /opt/flink/lib/myflink.jar &

# Prevent the script from immediately exiting
trap "echo 'Script is running...'; wait" SIGINT SIGTERM

# Wait for the Flink job to complete
wait
```

Need to submit jar file through automation/CI/CD. Above flink run command works fine when I login to pod and submit manually. Facing issue only when submiting through ENTRYPOING in dockerfile